# How to read a file in a do block

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting an error on the following piece of code. I'm trying to define a function that can read a file at a given location, and perform some function on it, but it has an error that I'm afraid I can't get my head around.

I imagine I'm doing something stupid but I can't figure out what; can someone tell me?

```hs
readAndProcessFile ::  String -> (String -> a) -> a
readAndProcessFile l f = do
    contents <- readFile l -- error here
    let result = f contents
    return result
```

I get the error:

---

Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ IO a

In a stmt of a 'do' block: contents <- readFile l

In the expression:

```
do contents <- readFile l
   let result = (f contents)
   return result
```

In an equation for ‘readAndProcessFile’:

```
  readAndProcessFile l f
    = do contents <- readFile l
         let result = ...
         return result
```

• Relevant bindings include

```
f :: String -> a
readAndProcessFile :: String -> (String -> a) -> a
```

---

Comment: the type of `readAndProcessFIle` is `String -> (String -> a) -> IO a`.

Comment: That's very useful, thanks - am I right in thinking that there's no way to have this return `a` instead of `IO a`?

Comment: @OliverRadini: well the idea of `IO` is exactly to add a layer to make this impossible (well you can use `unsafePerformIO`, but that is, like the name suggests, unsafe).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Understood - appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the type of `readAndProcessFile` is `String -> (String -> a) -> IO a`. Indeed, you use a `do` block, so that means it is monadic. What you here basically write is `readFile >>= \contents -> let result = f contents in return result`. The `readFile` furthermore specializes this to an `IO`.

You can simplify the expression by making use of [**`<$> :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-)

```
readAndProcessFile :: FilePath -> (String -> a) -> IO a
readAndProcessFile l f = f <$> readFile l
```